# Wifi Frequency Band

Tags: wifi, android-wifi

At present, I know that the country code has done some processing on the wifi frequency band, but I don't know how it works.  May I ask what factors are related to this wifi frequency band?  Do you have any relevant materials to provide.

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: @Eisverygoodletter  For now I want to limit the frequency band of the wifi module.  I know country code is one way, is there any other way to do it besides country code?